# How do I know the direction of my TiKZ circuit element?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib

I'm trying to create my own symbols for current and voltage sources - basically I want the current source as an encircled arrow in the direction of the current, and the voltage source as a + and - inside a circle, showing the direction of the potential difference.

I've gotten far enough to start to draw things on circles to create these elements, but I can't figure out how to get the orientation right - please see the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\tikzset{set current source graphic = current source IEC graphic}
\tikzset{current source IEC graphic/.style={
    circuit symbol lines,
    circuit symbol size = width 3 height 3,
    shape = generic circle IEC,
    /pgf/generic circle IEC/before background={
        % What do I put here?
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-.5pt) -- (0,.5pt);
    }
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,scale=5]
\draw (0,0) to[current source] (2,0) 
            to[current source] (2,2) 
            to[current source] (0,2) 
            to[current source] (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

The arrows render OK, but they all point up, regardless of the orientation of the circuit element. I'd like the arrows to point along the direction of the element, which in this case is counter-clockwise in the circuit (i.e. the right one is correct, and the others are not).

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Does `transform shape` do the job?

Comment: It might, if I knew how to use it. Would you care to give me an example?

Comment: Sorry it does not seem to work in this case... Not sure why.

Comment: Hm, I think I've found my problem, stated clearly on page 314-315 in the pgf manual - referring to the code within the `before background` key: "When the code is executed, the coordinate system will have been transformed in such a way that 314the point (1pt, 0pt) lies at the right end of the circle and (0pt, 1pt) lies at the top of the circle." This seems to be regardless of the orientation of the element, so whatever I do it will still be rotated back. Sigh... Any suggestion of a way around this is much appreciated.

Comment: In the meantime, I'll direct the arrow left-to-right (since standard for circuit elements is to be that direction when un-rotated) and then use `point up` etc to get the rotation right.

Comment: I'm looking at the same page of the manual and wondering if there's a way to use the `input` and `output` anchors of `circle ee`. That could help I guess.

Comment: Is it a useful solution to enter `current source={point up}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`transform shape` does the job, as suggested by Peter Grill above.  The following style definition works for me.

```
\tikzset{current source IEC graphic/.style={
    circuit symbol lines,
    circuit symbol size = width 3 height 3,
    shape = generic circle IEC,
    /pgf/generic circle IEC/before background={
        % What do I put here?
        %\draw[->,thick] (0,-.5pt) -- (0,.5pt);
        \draw[->,thick] (-.5pt,0) -- (.5pt,0);
    },
    transform shape
}}
```

Comment: Perfect - this works just as I want it to! Thanks! =)